# Camel context properties from DB

Tags: spring, apache-camel

Right now, I bootstrap Camel using Spring. Using Spring, I can point my Camel contexts to their respective properties files which are then injected at boot time. My issues is that I now want to move my properties from a file to a database, yet still be able to use the property placeholders as I was before. What's the best way to go about doing this?

I've noticed that there's a `PropertiesResolver` interface that I could implement, but I wouldn't know how to tell Camel about my implementation. Camel's documentation is very lacking in this area.

I also wouldn't be opposed to having Spring get the properties from the database for me, although I don't see that happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought I'd update this with what I found to work. This probably isn't the best method way to do it, but it works and I didn't have to modify the Camel source code. Basically, I converted all of my classes from inheriting from RouteBuilder to inherit from GJKRouteBuilder (which inherits from RouteBuilder). Then in there, I did this:

```
public class GJKRouteBuilder extends RouteBuilder {
    @Override
    protected void checkInitialized() throws Exception {
        //Get properties from CamelContext using getContext()
        //Lookup properties from DB based on CamelContext
        //Get the properties component from the context (or create one)
        //call setOverrideProperties() on properties component
        super.checkInitialized();
    }
}
```

Again, probably not the best method, but it works. Now, any route that inherits from GJKRouteBuilder and has the proper values wired up through Spring will have the properties injected into the properties component as if they were coming right from a properties file.

Answer (score 0):

The PropertiesResolver was designed to help Camel to locate the properties files from OSGi bundle or normal class path.

If you want to setup your owner **PropertiesResolver**, you can try to use **org.apache.camel.spring.spi.BridgePropertyPlaceholderConfigurer**.

You can inject your customer implementation of **PropertiesResolver** there.

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't seem to work as I'd hoped, making it impossible to pull the properties from the DB. I've figured out a way to do what I want, but I've run into another issue along the way (that I think is orthogonal to this one). http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17731225/camel-custom-propertiescomponent When I figure out the answer to that question, I'll update this one.