# Camel custom PropertiesComponent

Tags: spring, apache-camel

I'm trying to configure a custom PropertiesComponent for my CamelContexts via Spring. According to [this](http://camel.apache.org/properties.html) page, I simply need to add a bean definition of type `org.apache.camel.component.properties.PropertiesComponent`. However, my CamelContext isn't picking it and I can't seem to find a way to reference the bean from within the CamelContext. I just keep getting the following error:

```
PropertiesComponent with name properties must be defined in CamelContext to support property placeholders.
```

How can add a PropertiesComponent to the context via Spring? (I do **not** want to use the `propertyPlaceholder` tag.)

What I have so far. (I'll subclass PropertiesComponent as soon as I can get this working.)

```
<bean id="properties" class="org.apache.camel.component.properties.PropertiesComponent">
    <property name="location" value="classpath:props.properties" />
</bean>

<camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring" id="eventService">
    <routeBuilder ref="httpInbound" />
</camelContext>
```

Comment: What Camel version do you use?

Answer (score 0):

When you define the `properties` object inside the spring application context, camel will look up the PropertiesComponent from the Spring application context by using that name.

Comment: That's my problem, it should be doing that, but it's not. It just gives me the error that I posted, signaling that either Camel can't find the component I'm declaring, or it's ignoring it.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you are experiencing [this camel regression](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-6313?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3aall-tabpanel) - if so, you can upgrade to 2.11.1 in which it is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try defining property placeholder inside camel context?

```
<camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring" id="eventService">
    <propertyPlaceholder id="properties" location="classpath:props.properties"/>

    <routeBuilder ref="httpInbound" />
</camelContext>
```